# Transparent PNG over JPEG using HTML,CSS not working

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I have a HTML,

1)Which has a div with class images.

**HTML**

```
<div class="images">
      <a href="http://dynamicUrl.com/reload.jpg" itemprop="image"   
    class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" 
        title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">
        <img width="454" height="600" 
src="http://cutomPicture.com/OK-454x600.jpg" 
class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image"
 alt="men grey" title="men grey"></a>
```

**CSS:**
1)

```
.single-product .images,
```

2)

```
.images img {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  padding: .618em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e4e3;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This HTML show a box and renders a dynamic image through dynamic generated URL.

I tried adding `background-image:url('TransparentPicture.png')` Inside `.Images img{}` css but it display transparent png image in background. And Image from anchor tag in html comes front.

This is code from WooCommerce plugin, I am trying to override the single pproduct image by showing a fix transparent png over the images which are shown in singple forduct image box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a wrapper html over your `<img>`:

```
<div class="images">
     <div class="imgWrapper">
      <a href="http://dynamicUrl.com/reload.jpg" itemprop="image"   
    class="woocommerce-main-image zoom" 
        title="" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">
        <img width="454" height="600" 
src="http://cutomPicture.com/OK-454x600.jpg" 
class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image"
 alt="men grey" title="men grey"></a></div>
```

Try adding these styles:

```
.imgWrapper {
  position:relative;
}

.imgWrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-image:url('TransparentPicture.png');
  background-position:center;
}
```

This adds a pseudo-element and positions it on top of the `<img>`

Comment: @Vedant Kekan: Can you resize the background image to fit with the product image? Or try `background-position:center`

Comment: @Vedant Kekan: You can try `background-size: 454px 600px;` (the same size as your `img`), but it may distort your image.

Comment: @Vedant Kekan: It's better to resize your physical image, it's displayed better and also with higher performance because the browser does not need to manipulate the image.

Comment: You are right, I will do that, Thank for your all help :)

Answer (score 0):

.images {
  position:relative;
}

.images .transparent {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
Width:100%;
Height:100%
}

Add above css and add transparent class to img tag

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but my preferred way to do this would be to place two images at the same coordinates using relative or absolute positioning and then using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to layer them correctly. The image with the highest z-index will be the one on top.